# How to create a Windows 7 installation USB from Linux or Mac?

Tags: windows, usb

I have a Windows 7 installation DVD that came with a computer with no optical drive. I have an empty USB thumb drive. I have access to two computers with optical drives, one running Linux and the other running Mac OS X.

Notably, I do not have access to any Windows computer at this time. With the tools that I have, how can I create a thumb drive that I can boot with and install Windows 7?

Do I have to look out for anything when making the ISO from the DVD (DRM or anything)?

After the ISO is made, will UNetbootin work? How about dd?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question -- let's assume your flash drive is sdc and your ISO is called w7.iso.

I guess the most short and hassle-free answer is to ask if your motherboard supports USB-CDROM style booting, because if so you can just DD the image directly to the raw device:

```
dd if=w7.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

If not, you will need [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/), and then you will need to do something like the following:

First unmount the USB disk...

```
umount /dev/sdc
```

Then go into fdisk...

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
```

Once you're in fdisk, delete each partition by using `d` and then inputting the number of the respective partition. Now create an entirely new partition filling the disk by doing the following sequence: `n`, `p`, `1`, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. After that check it's done with `p`. Now set it as an NTFS partition with `t`, then `7`, and give it the boot flag with `a`, `1`, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Finally press w to write the table to the usb stick.

Put the filesystem on the partition by running the following as root:

```
mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdc1
```

Now you're going to need to mount the iso as a vnd. To do this, do the following...

```
mkdir /mnt/iso
mount -o loop w7.iso /mnt/iso
```

And now mount the USB stick again...

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb
```

Copy everything recursively from the loop mount to the USB disk...

```
cp -a /mnt/iso /media/usb
```

Write the master boot record to boot from...

```
ms-sys -7 /dev/sdc (use -m for WinXP)
```

And there you go (hopefully).

I tried something similar to this on my Debian machine and it worked, this is a bit of a tweaked version.

Comment: You also need to format the ntfs partition with mkfs.

Comment: sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdc1 step missing.  Also to enable the boot flag you type "a" then "1" then enter.

Comment: @MattH: where should I do that step? This is a community wiki, you can modify the answer instead of commenting. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'cp -a /mnt/iso/* /media/usb', otherwise I get a folder called iso inside /media/usb